# How can I drop my secondary database instances I created from multiple database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

Is there a way to drop my secondary database instances instead of deleting the project?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no mechanism to delete a database shard.  If this is something you want, please [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

If your shard is empty, you will not be paying any more than if it was not present, as it neither contains nor serves any data.